# dynamodb query remove response duplicates in columns specified in ProjectionExpression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Assume the following table, A is partition key, B is sort key:

```
A    B    C
a1   b1   c1
a1   b2   c1
a1   b3   c1
a1   b4   c2
```

If queried with KeyConditionExpression `A=a1`, ProjectionExpression `C`,
return would be `[c1, c1, c1, c2]`.

But I would like it to be `[c1, c2]`, i.e. remove the duplicate `c1`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is currently not possible.

Also, compared to removing duplicates by yourself after you received the result, would be a smaller result set is  (and therefore maybe a little faster transmission). Even if it was possible the query would consume the same throughput capacity because DynamoDB internally would also need to query all results and *then* remove duplicates.

Comment: is it still the case?